# Web App for Containers displayed only default page when deployed using docker image

Tags: docker, docker-image, azure-container-registry, azure-web-app-for-containers

I created Container registry and then push the docker image of my web app to that registry. Created container instance and it is working fine.

Now i have to deploy this image to the Web App. There are two option which i found.

First i can choose 'Deploy to web app' option directly where docker image is stored.
Second i can create 'Web App for container' resource using the same docker image.

a.) When i tried first option : After deployed successfully when i run the web app it displayed default page. When i connected to the ftp to check the files in wwwroot folder. Only 'hostingstart.html' file is present.

b.) When i tried second option : After deployed successfully when i run the web app it displayed message displayed on page 'The Web App's container could not start. Please try again in few minutes. If you are an administrator of this Web App please verify your container settings and go to Azure Portal to review the diagnostic logs' 
When i connected to the ftp to check the files in wwwroot folder. Only 'hostingstart.html' file is present.

Docker image has no issue as i am able to run it locally and on container instance.

My first question is : Is the above two methods are same thing beacuse in first method it looks like normal web app with kudu/app service editor option available but in second method i do not found kudu/app service editor support.

Second question is : I want to implement web app for container so only second option is the one i should go for?

Any idea what i am missing?

Comment: I push the image again to the container and it works automatically.

Comment: Is this resolved?

Comment: @KarishmaTiwari-MSFT Yes

Answer (score 0):

As shared by the original poster in the comments, retrying pushing the image to the container worked.